# Producing a 'clean' tuple from a unproper format

Tags: python, tuples

When ever I call a database search between date ranges in my program it returns this

```
'(', (4, u'Jake', u'Ryan', u'Bowman', 1, 8, u'12/13/13'), ')', '(', (5, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 0, 10, u'12/13/13'), ')',          '(', (6, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 8, 8, u'12/25/13'), ')',
```

What would be the best way to return this value in a format such as this:

```
(4,'Jake','Ryan','Bowman',1,8,'12/13/13'),(5,'Kate','Brian','Adams',0,10 '12/13/13'), etc
```

Never mind the unicode, I just need a tuple in which I can use within the csv library.

Answer (score 1):

You could drop it into a list like this:

```
>>> t = ['(', (4, u'Jake', u'Ryan', u'Bowman', 1, 8, u'12/13/13'), ')', '(', (5, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 0, 10, u'12/13/13'), ')',          '(', (6, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 8, 8, u'12/25/13'), ')', ]
>>> t = [row for row in t if row not in ('(', ')')]
>>> t
[(4, u'Jake', u'Ryan', u'Bowman', 1, 8, u'12/13/13'), (5, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 0, 10, u'12/13/13'), (6, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 8, 8, u'12/25/13')]
```

You primarily need to drop the parens strings. The result can easily be dropped into a csv file.

Comment: Thank you so much I wish I had enough rep to think you! This has been bugging me for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

filter the list and keep the tuples.

```
result = ['(', (4, u'Jake', u'Ryan', u'Bowman', 1, 8, u'12/13/13'), ')', '(', (5, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 0, 10, u'12/13/13'), ')',          '(', (6, u'Katie', u'Brian', u'Adams', 8, 8, u'12/25/13'), ')', ]
tuples = [t for t in result if isinstance(t, tuple)]
```